# iphone - problem with debugging on a device

Tags: iphone, debugging, ipod-touch

When I run my application in the simulator everything works perfectly. It couldn't be any more sweet! :p

However when I change to debugging on a device (ipod touch) everything starts going haywire, with NO cause.

After a few seconds of the application being open (it will work for about 10s) it quits unexpectedly. XCode console gives no explaination (no EXC_BAD_ACCESS or anything - the app just quits) except to tell me that `The Program being debugged is not being run`.

Unplugging the device and running the app again results in the application running perfectly - until I get to a certain part where it will go funny - stalling and hanging - and will crash. The crash report says nothing interesting except:

```
Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Occationally it will work as prescribed (the app is supposed to download a video off the internet, save it to a file on the iphone, and then play it - when it has checked for its existance), until you come to play the video when the video lasts for about 8 seconds and is just a black screen.

My problem is that I have absolutely NO IDEA where to start debugging this! When I run the debug on the device it doesn't `NSLog` anything to the console! :(

Any ideas where to start or why this is happening?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Are you certain you're building with the Debug Build Configuration? Also check that you are using "Build and Debug (Breakpoints On)" and not just "Build and Run" (These options are in the Build). Have you edited any aspects of your Debug Build Configuration? Finally, have you tried turning it off an on again? ;) (but seriously, restart your computer and the iPod if you haven't already).

Comment: none of these work. :( I've got the debug working again by setting `get-task-allow` to true in Entitlements.plist (didn't realise an Ad-hoc release didn't support debugging :( ) app still works perfectly in simulator, but hangs/crashes on device. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewrote parts of the class - seems to work fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check:

Your app is not running in the simulator.  Just to be safe, entirely quit the simulator.

Verify that Debug configuration is selected in the drop-down, and not Distribution (or something else).